# What exactly does tell() return, and how do I use it to calculate percent of file read?

Tags: python, tell

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows, and I am very new to Python so forgive me if this is an easy one.

Everything that I have read says that tell() returns the "position", which I believe is basically the cursor position that we are currently at in the read.  OK, that sounds helpful, but I cannot figure out how to find the total "positions" of the file to calculate a percentage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could seek to the end of the file, then call `.tell()`:

```
import os

fileobj.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
size = fileobj.tell()
fileobj.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
```

The above example uses the [`os.SEEK_*` constants](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.SEEK_SET) to set how to interpret the seek offset (the first argument to `.seek()`).

or you can use the [`os.fstat()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fstat) to retrieve the size of your open file:

```
import os

size = os.fstat(fileobj.fileno()).st_size
```

The latter information can be more easily cached by the OS so will often be faster.

Comment: @BrendanLong: You can pretty much count on me editing my posts to add documentation and clarifications as I go along. :-) Thanks for your edit, but it clashed with what I was adding myself.

Comment: Blair Connolly: You can also get the size of a file directly with `os.stat('somefile.txt').st_size`. For an already open one you can use `os.fstat(fileobj.fileno()).st_size`.

Comment: @martineau: Yup, and it's *often* faster too.

Comment: Thanks, guys, fast and helpful!